# How to create a global variable that can be accessed in all layers of the application. Accessing an element ID and updating

Tags: android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to update a text dynamically but without success. clicking on a button the text is updated

Comment: You can share data through the composition tree using [CompositionLocal](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/CompositionLocal) (instead of passing it as parameter). If this doesn't answer your question, then please provide a bit more details for your use case.